# Problems with web_socket_channel under MacOS

Tags: flutter, websocket

I have the following sample application:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/web_socket_channel.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const title = 'WebSocket Demo';
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: MyHomePage(
        title: title,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
    required this.title,
  });

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  late final WebSocketChannel _channel;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(
      Uri.parse('wss://ws.postman-echo.com/raw'),
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Form(
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Send a message'),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 24),
            StreamBuilder(
              stream: _channel.stream,
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Text(snapshot.hasData ? '${snapshot.data}' : '');
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _sendMessage,
        tooltip: 'Send message',
        child: const Icon(Icons.send),
    );
  }

  void _sendMessage() {
    if (_controller.text.isNotEmpty) {
      _channel.sink.add(_controller.text);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _channel.sink.close();
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

everything works fine when run on iOS simulator, in Android emulator and in Chrome. However, same code run as MacOS app doesn't work!
Do I have to change anything in the configuration of the desktop app? Anything in plist.info? Runner Workspace? Anywhere else?

Here is my flutter configuration:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.3, on macOS 12.6 21G115 darwin-arm, locale de-DE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.0.1)
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced quite a similar issue. I make an app using web socket on flutter.
Although I use different web socket library (websocket_universal), it works on iOS and web but not on MacOS.

I follow this comment and it works for my case.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47606#issuecomment-568522318

> Add
>
> ```
>     <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
>     <true/>
> ```
>
> to file `DebugProfile.entitlements` under directory `macos/Runner/`